# backbone collection add does not trigger model validate

Tags: validation, backbone.js, collections, addition

I am rather new to backbone and wanted to test a simple script that handles a to do list. Here is the code i used so far:

```
(function() {

    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {}
    };

    window.template = function(id) {
        return _.template($('#' + id).html());
    }

    App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
        validate: function(attributes) {
            if ( !$.trim(attributes.title) ) {
                return 'Invalid title';
            }
        }
    });
    App.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Task
    });
    App.Views.Task = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: template('taskTemplate'),
        initialize: function () {
            this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
            this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
        },
        events: {
            'click .edit': 'editTask',
            'click .delete': 'destroy'
        },
        destroy: function() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                this.model.destroy();
            }
        },
        remove: function() {
            this.$el.remove();
        },
        editTask: function() {
            var newTaskTitle = prompt('New title:', this.model.get('title'));
            this.model.set('title', newTaskTitle, {validate: true});
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
    App.Views.AddTask = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'form#addTask',
        initialize: function() {

        },
        events: {
            'submit': 'submit'
        },
        submit: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var newTaskTitle = $(event.currentTarget).find('input[type=text]').val();
            var task = new App.Models.Task({ title: newTaskTitle });
            this.collection.add(task, {add: true, merge: false, remove: false});
        }
    });
    App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        initialize: function() {
            this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
            return this;
        },
        addOne: function(task) {
            var taskView = new App.Views.Task({ model: task });
            this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
        }
    });

    var tasks = new App.Collections.Tasks([
        {
            title: 'Go to store',
            priority: 4
        },
        {
            title: 'Go to mall',
            priority: 3
        },
        {
            title: 'Get to work',
            priority: 5
        }
    ]);
    var addTaskView = new App.Views.AddTask({ collection: tasks });
    var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks({ collection: tasks });
    $('div.tasks').append(tasksView.render().el);
})();
```

So the model validation works fine ... the only pb is that collection.add does not validate the newly added model .... is the a way to force the validation?

Thanks,
Rares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate):

> **validate** `model.validate(attributes, options)`
>
> [...] By default **validate** is called before `save`, but can also be
>   called before `set` if `{validate:true}` is passed.

`Collection#add` does not call `save` nor does it call `set` with the `validate: true` option. If you want to validate during `add`, say so:

```
collection.add(models, { validate: true });
```

That will get `validate:true` all that way down to `Model#set`.

A quick look at a simplified example may be helpful:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    set: function() {
        console.log('setting...');
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    validate: function() {
        console.log('validating...');
        return 'Never!';
    }
});
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: M
});
var c = new C;
c.on('add', function() {
    console.log('Added: ', arguments);
});
c.on('invalid', function() {
    console.log('Error: ', arguments);
});
```

Now if we do this (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7NqPg/):

```
c.add(
    { where: 'is', pancakes: 'house?' },
    { validate: true }
);
```

You'll see that `set` is called with `validate: true`, `validate` will be called, and you'll get an error. But if you say this (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7b2mn/):

```
c.add(
    { where: 'is', pancakes: 'house?' },
    {add: true, merge: false, remove: false} // Your options
);
```

You'll see that `set` is called without `validate: true`, `validate` will **not** be called, and the model will be added to the collection.

---

The above behavior is quite strongly implied but not explicitly specified so you may not want to trust it. [`Model#initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) does say:

> you can pass in the initial values of the **attributes**, which will be `set` on the model.

and [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) does explicitly mention the `validate` option. However, there is no guarantee that `Collection#add` will send options to the model constructor or `set` or that the model's constructor will send the options to `set`. So if you want to be really paranoid and future proof, you could add a quick check for this "options get all the way down to `set`" behavior to your test suite; then, if it changes you'll know about it and you can fix it.

Comment: thanks ... one quick note to the newbies like me ... if u send to the add method an instance of the model `{ validate: true }` won't work ... but if u send an object containing the model attributes and `{ validate: true }` will work (will call the validate function) .... so again ... **this does not work => `var task = new App.Models.Task({ title: newTaskTitle }); collection.add({ title: newTaskTitle }, { validate: true });`** .... **this works => `collection.add({ title: newTaskTitle }, { validate: true });`**

Answer (score 1):

if you pass options to your collection add method, the validation method will not be called and as your arguments in this case are all set to the default value, there is not need to pass them

```
 this.collection.add(task);
```

you may want to take a look at this question.
[Prevent Backbone.js model from validating when first added to collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634088/prevent-backbone-js-model-from-validating-when-first-added-to-collection)

Comment: You'll note that nikoshr's answer includes an important caveat: "it may break things down the line". The options trickery no longer works as the way collections work has changed.